# Windows 7 NNTP Server

Tags: windows, windows-7, nntp

I am doing some development that requires some interaction with an NNTP server, however I don't want to develop against a live server for obvious reasons and am trying to get a local NNTP server setup for testing, but for the life of me I can't find any guides on setting one up in (preferably) Windows 7.

Can anyone shed some light? I've found that in IIS 6 you were able to setup an NNTP server, but I unfortunately do not have a 2003 VM at my disposal, I'm stuck with either XP or Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows client OSs do not have an NNTP server option. You will have to use a third-party package.

Check out the [DMOZ list of NNTP servers](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Software/Internet/Servers/Usenet/) for some third party options.

Comment: Or put up a VM with some Linux distro and setup an NNTP server there. This way you keep your workstation clean from uncessary cruft.

Comment: @SvenW Do you have any recommendations as to NNTP servers for Linux? I went through trying to configure a number of them in Ubuntu but didn't have luck with any of them, including some of what appear to be the well known ones such as leafnode and inn.

I need something that will act purely as a local news server and not try to download news or submit news anywhere else. That way I can test posting to the news server without cluttering up an actual news group.

Comment: @SvenW Thank you also for adding the NNTP tag to my post for me :)